# Need to make a laptop charger

Tags: power-supply, charger, ac-dc

I am not an electrician. My laptop's charger burned when we had high voltage 2 days ago. My laptops charger says Output is: 19.5 V and 9.23 A. I am in a country that you can't easily find those kinds of things. I had an idea, but wanted to make sure it works. Can I use two chargers with 19.5 V and 4.0 A? I will just merge the + to + and - to -. Will this actually work?
If not what will happen if I just use one charger with 19.5 V and 4.0 A? Will that make any damage to my computer or to the charger itself?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why this question is off topic? Where can I ask this kind of question? I would be happy to move my question if this is not a right place.

Comment: @PeterJ Yes, if superuser is best place than I am ok with moving this to superuser. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connecting two chargers in parallel cannot be considered a great idea. It will likely be OK when there is a load present, but when there is no load, if one of them has a slightly lower output voltage, current may flow into that charger and damage it. Using identical chargers improves the chance that it will be OK.

I also have to point out that 4A + 4A is still less than 9.23A. So even with two, you are under-powered.

Assuming the 4A charger is well designed (has all the agency markings such as CE mark, UL, or whatever) it is not likely that it will be damaged when you connect it to a laptop that tries to draw more than 4A. But something will happen. The charger will cut out (due to over-current or over-temperature), or the voltage will drop dramatically when the current limit is exceeded. So I don't think that will work, or at least not under heavy load conditions (charging battery plus running system). The chances are better if the laptop is powered off. Then at least it only has to supply the charging current, but not the system current.

Another point about that. The charging current will be regulated. So if you are capable of measuring the current coming out of the charger while recharging the batteries with the system powered off, you should do it. If it is under 4A, then it should be safe to recharge that way.

I think it is unlikely that you will damage your computer whether you use two in parallel or one. Any time you abuse equipment like this, there is some chance of starting a fire or having other unexpected bad things occur. Keep that in mind.